# PHP MySql scores page for a game

Tags: php, mysql

What would be the logic on scores page to get:

- current user order among all players (like #115): MySql SELECT for all users ORDER BY score DESC and then check where is the current user?
- better two scores: Get current user and then SELECT LIMIT 2 WHERE score > "$currentuserscore"?
- less two scores: Get current user and then SELECT LIMIT 2 WHERE score < "$currentuserscore"?

I feel this is very buggy, is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For option 1:

`select count(1) as count from users where score>=$user_score`

This should give you the person's rank. If you worried about multiple people having the same score as the current user change the `>=` to a `>` then you can add 1 to the result.

For option 2 and 3:

`select * from users where score>$user_score order by score asc limit 2`

`select * from users where score<$user_score order by score desc limit 2`

Or you could get all 5 (2 before, 2 after and current user) in one query once you have the rank from first query:

```
$start = $user_rank - 2;
$query = "select * from users order by score asc limit {$start},5";
```

Or if you didn't want current user or anyone with the same score as the current user to be included you could do this:

```
$start = $user_rank - 2;
$query = "select * from users where score!=$user_score order by score asc limit {$start},4";
```

Comment: Thanks dude this was a great help